# how to store a string with newline into php array

Tags: php, arrays, string, newline

My goal is to store a newline character in an array. I want to display it later on a site.

```
$settings['standard'] = array(
            'title'       => __( 'Standard', 'foo' ),
            'description' => __( 'description text with 
newline character', 'fooMore' ));
```

the output have to something like this:

> description text with 
>  newline character

Comment: if showed inside a html element why not use old <br> ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$settings['standard'] = array(
        'title'       => __( 'Standard', 'foo' ),
        'description' => __( 'description text with' . PHP_EOL . 'newline character', 'fooMore' ));
```

PHP_EOL is the End Of Line character for your current environment (LF, CR or CRLF).